# Writing a C Program to Delete Space Between Strings

Tags: c

I want to create a program that removes space between characters in a string.

Here is my code:

```
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){ 
    char  str[10]="I love you",temp[20];
    int i,j;  
    for(i=0;str[i];i++){     
        if(str[i] ==" "){              
        }    
        else{         
            temp[j]=str[i];       
            j++;
        }
    } 
    temp[j]='\0'; 
    strcpy(str,temp); 
    printf("%s",str);  
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Try printing out the characters so you can debug the code and actually see what is happening.

Comment: 1) initialize `j` E.g `int i,j=0;` 2) `if(str[i] ==" ") {` --> `if(str[i] ==' ') {` 3) `char  str[10]="I love you"` --> `char  str[11]="I love you"` or `char  str[]="I love you"`

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your program.

Though this initialization of a character array is valid in C

```
char  str[10]="I love you",temp[20];
         ^^^^
```

nevertheless the array `str` will not contain the terminating zero of the string literal `"I love you"` because the string literal contains 11 characters including the terminating zero. This makes some difficulties in processing of the array.

It is better to declare the array either like

```
char  str[11]="I love you",temp[20];
         ^^^^
```

or like

```
char  str[]="I love you",temp[20];
         ^^^^
```

In this case the array will contain the terminating zero.

In this statement

```
if(str[i] ==" ") {
            ^^^^
```

there is compared a character with a pointer because the string literal `" "` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character.

I think you mean a character constant instead of the string literal

```
if(str[i] == ' ') {
             ^^^^
```

Take into account that variable `j` was not initialized. So the program has undefined behavior. At least you should write

```
int i,j = 0;
      ^^^^^
```

And the program can be written without using an auxiliary array.

It could look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char  str[] = "I love you";

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( str[i] && str[i] != ' ' ) i++;

    size_t j = i;

    while ( str[i] )
    {
        if ( str[++i] != ' ' ) str[j++] = str[i];
    }

    puts( str );
}
```

Its output is

```
Iloveyou
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using double quotes to reference a single character - comparing it to a single char[] element in your string, you should use single quotes:

```
if (str[i] == ' ')
```

Also, not 100% here so maybe  someone can confirm - the inactive/empty if condition may throw up at least a warning, try changing it to:

```
if (str[i] != ' ') {
    temp[j]=str[i];
    j++;
}
```

Hope that helps.

ETA - I just want to add so that you don't end up back here again :p

You're packing a string byte by byte, when we assign strings to buffers in c using double quotes like:

```
char str[10] = "I love you";
```

We create a string that is terminated with a NUL byte or \0:

```
temp[0] = '\0';
```

For example - using single-quotes to refer to a single character - when you pack your string:

```
temp[j]=str[i];
```

You should add the \0 byte at the end so functions like strcpy() and printf() know when the string ends

So when you copy temp to str, strcpy won't know where your string ends, you need to add that \0 byte. This also means that you are overwriting str...because str has 10 elements, "I love you" including spaces is 10 bytes...but it's really 11, because when youa ssign the string the \0 is automatically added at the end for you...you are packing your temp string by hand so you need to add the \0 yourself:

```
if (str[i] != ' ') {
    temp[j]=str[i];
    temp[++j] = '\0';
}
```

I'd change the entire loop to:

```
for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(str[i] != ' ') {
        temp[j++] = str[i];
        temp[j] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Oughtta do it, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Welp this worked for me i just searched up a bit.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"stdafx.h"
int main(void) 
{
    char  str[11] = "I love you", str2;


    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != ' ') dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

(It returns Iloveyou)